# How do I make this code output a second node?

Tags: android, xml-serialization

How do I get this to output a second node?  Currently it seems to just right over the top of the old data.  My Instructor says it should work but it doesn't.

```
protected void ModifyXMLFile(String sName, String sClue1, String sClue2,
                String sClue3, String sAnswer, String sLocation, String sPoints) {
            // Write Data to a File in XML Format

            try {
                FileOutputStream mOutput = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                //we create a XmlSerializer in order to write xml data

                XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();

                try {

                    //we set the FileOutputStream as output for the serialize, using UTF-8 encoding

                    serializer.setOutput(mOutput, "UTF-8");

                    //Write <?xml declaration with encoding (if encoding not null) and stand alone flag (if stand alone not null)

                    serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));

                    //set indentation option

                    serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);

                    //start a tag called "root"
                    serializer.startTag(null, "Items");

                    //i indent code just to have a view similar to xml-tree
                    serializer.startTag(null, "Treasure");

                        serializer.startTag(null, "Name");
                        serializer.attribute(null, "Name", sName);
                        serializer.endTag(null, "Name");

                        serializer.startTag(null, "Clue1");
                        serializer.attribute(null, "Clue1", sClue1);
                        serializer.endTag(null, "Clue1");

                        serializer.startTag(null, "Clue2");
                        serializer.attribute(null, "Clue2", sClue2);
                        serializer.endTag(null, "Clue2");

                        serializer.startTag(null, "Clue3");
                        serializer.attribute(null, "Clue3", sClue3);
                        serializer.endTag(null, "Clue3");

                        serializer.startTag(null, "Answer");
                        serializer.attribute(null, "Answer", sAnswer);
                        serializer.endTag(null, "Answer");

                        serializer.startTag(null, "Location");
                        serializer.attribute(null, "Location", sLocation);
                        serializer.endTag(null, "Location");

                        serializer.startTag(null, "Points");
                        serializer.attribute(null, "Points", sPoints);
                        serializer.endTag(null, "Points");

                    serializer.endTag(null, "Treasure");

                serializer.endTag(null, "Items");


                serializer.endDocument();

                //write xml data into the FileOutputStream

                serializer.flush();

                //finally we close the file stream

                mOutput.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("Exception","error occurred while creating xml file");

                }

             //   mOutput.write(data.getBytes());
             //   mOutput.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
```

The Current output looks like this.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<Items>
  <Treasure>
    <Name Name="p" />
    <Clue1 Clue1="l" />
    <Clue2 Clue2="m" />
    <Clue3 Clue3="o" />
    <Answer Answer="k" />
    <Location Location="n" />
    <Points Points="i" />
  </Treasure>
</Items>
```

And it should look like this after a second time through.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<Items>
  <Treasure>
    <Name Name="Treasure 1" />
    <Clue1 Clue1="l" />
    <Clue2 Clue2="m" />
    <Clue3 Clue3="o" />
    <Answer Answer="k" />
    <Location Location="n" />
    <Points Points="i" />
  </Treasure>
 <Treasure>
    <Name Name="Treasure 2" />
    <Clue1 Clue1="b" />
    <Clue2 Clue2="c" />
    <Clue3 Clue3="d" />
    <Answer Answer="e" />
    <Location Location="f" />
    <Points Points="g" />
  </Treasure>
</Items>
```

ok I added the following changes

```
FileOutputStream mOutput = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Activity.MODE_APPEND);
```

I also added this line as it seemed to be missing.

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
```

I am getting the same thing I was getting when I started this.  There has to be a better way.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<Items>
  <Treasure>
    <Name Name="quit" />
    <Clue1 Clue1="was" />
    <Clue2 Clue2="each" />
    <Clue3 Clue3="race" />
    <Answer Answer="the" />
    <Location Location="life" />
    <Points Points="35" />
  </Treasure>
</Items><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<Items>
  <Treasure>
    <Name Name="zone" />
    <Clue1 Clue1="Xbox" />
    <Clue2 Clue2="city" />
    <Clue3 Clue3="very" />
    <Answer Answer="but" />
    <Location Location="new" />
    <Points Points="12" />
  </Treasure>
</Items>
```

Comment: please post the current output and the expected output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code.

```
protected void ModifyXMLFile(String sName, String sClue1, String sClue2,
        String sClue3, String sAnswer, String sLocation, String sPoints) {

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = null;

        File file = getFileStreamPath(FILENAME);
        if(!file.exists()) {
            // Create an empty xml file
            FileOutputStream mOutput = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
            serializer.setOutput(mOutput, "UTF-8");
            serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
            serializer.startTag(null, "Items");
            serializer.endTag(null, "Items");
            serializer.endDocument();
            serializer.flush();
            mOutput.close();    
        }

        // Parse the existing xml file
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        doc = db.parse(fis);
        fis.close();

        // Append new Treasure
        Element treasure = doc.createElement("Treasure");
        treasure.appendChild(createChild(doc, "Name", sName));
        treasure.appendChild(createChild(doc, "Clue1", sClue1));
        treasure.appendChild(createChild(doc, "Clue2", sClue2));
        treasure.appendChild(createChild(doc, "Clue3", sClue3));
        treasure.appendChild(createChild(doc, "Answer", sAnswer));
        treasure.appendChild(createChild(doc, "Location", sLocation));
        treasure.appendChild(createChild(doc, "Points", sPoints));

        Element items = doc.getDocumentElement();
        items.appendChild(treasure);

        // Write the xml file
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        t.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        t.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(fos));
        fos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

private Element createChild(Document doc, String name, String value) {
    Element child = doc.createElement(name);
    child.setAttribute(name, value);
    return child;       
}
```

Comment: I had tried that it only ends up duplicateing the first 3 lines and the 2 ending tags, which is no longer an XML Format.

Comment: Activity.MODE_APPEND solves the problem of old data getting overwritten. The logic needs to be fixed as well. See this SO post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355824/how-to-append-tags-in-xml-in-android

Comment: I looked at the link you posted, but I was only missing one line.  I posted the results above.

Comment: Also that link is in complete the same as the Document the person who answered the problem from an IBM report.  In both cases instead of showing how to close and save what you have written they put in "return writer.toString();"  return to where????

Comment: The Code provided Above creates a empty file.

Comment: The above code is generating the expected output. Test it by calling the function and passing values as follows: ModifyXMLFile("quit", "was", "each", "race", "the", "life", "35"); Again with new values: ModifyXMLFile("zone", "Xbox", "city", "very", "but", "new", "12");

Comment: Yes you were correct, there must have been something in that file that prevented it from working correctly.  I deleted it and traced it all through and it worked.  One Question I have is that when I look at the file in notepade it has no NewLines after each end TAG.

Comment: The reason could be the way carriage return and line feed is treated by a particular editor. However, the output xml file can be validated through an XML validator. Try http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload+with_options